# Python mysql update doesnt update

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to read an excel file and update existing records in the database. New entries will be created for new records.

New entries are being created but updates are never reflected on the DB.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  port='3306',
  user="root",
  password="aaaaaa",
  database="aaaaaa",
  autocommit=True
)

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'msp.xlsx')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    rowIter = 2
    while sheet['A' + str(rowIter)].value != None and sheet['A' + str(rowIter)].value != '':
        item = sheet['A' + str(rowIter)].value

        try:
            if check_int(item):
                item = str(item)

            itemRegex = ' '.join(item.split())                        # removing extra spaces

            lp = sheet['B' + str(rowIter)].value if sheet['B' + str(rowIter)].value != None else 0
            msp = sheet['C' + str(rowIter)].value if sheet['C' + str(rowIter)].value != None else 0

            lp = 0 if check_int(str(lp)) == False else lp
            msp = 0 if check_int(str(msp)) == False else msp

            # checking if item already exists
            sql = "SELECT id FROM stock WHERE part_no = %s LIMIT 0, 1"
            val = (item, )
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            partFound = mycursor.fetchone()

            if partFound == None:
                # insert new record
                print('Creating new record')
                sql = "INSERT INTO stock (principal, part_no, balance, demo_pending, total, pending_sob, pending_po, reserved, msp, lp) VALUES (%s, %s, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, %s, %s);"
                val = (sheet.title, item, msp, lp, )
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)

            else:
                # updating existing record
                part_id = partFound[0]
                print('Updating record ' + str(part_id))

                sql =  "UPDATE stock SET msp = %s AND lp = %s WHERE id = %s;"
                val = (int(msp), int(lp), part_id, )
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)
                print "Row(s) were updated :" +  str(mycursor.rowcount)
                print(mycursor.statement)

        except Exception as e:
            print (str(e))
            break

        rowIter+=1

mydb.close()
```

Am I missing something ?

The `mycursor.rowcount` always returns `0`

Comment: Replace `AND` with a `,` in the update statement.

Comment: You should print your sql-statement, test it in a mysql client and than separate the topic. This is a (very simple) sql quesion.

Answer (score 1):

for updating a table, you should use:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

replace And with `,` in your code